# Reformulate indicator function using mixed integer program

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Consider the following constraint: $$ \sum_i I(a_i x \leq b) \leq m. $$
Can we reformulate this constraint using big-M constraint?

A similar question can be found in [Involving indicator function as a constraint in a LP problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220355/involving-indicator-function-as-a-constraint-in-a-lp-problem). The difference is we have the sum of indicator functions less than $m$ instead of greater than $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant tolerance,
introduce binary variables $y_i$ to represent the indicator, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &\le m \tag1 \\
b - a_i x + \epsilon &\le M_i y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces at most $m$ of the $y_i$ variables to be $1$.
Big-M constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_i = 0 \implies a_i x > b$, the contrapositive of $a_i x \le b \implies y_i = 1$.
If $a_i$, $x$, and $b$ are all integer, you can take $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, The constraint should be $b-a_i x+\epsilon \leq M_i y_i$? And the reformulation is actually equivalent to $\sum_i I(a_i x < b+\epsilon) \leq m$, am I correct?

Comment: Yes and yes.  I corrected the sign.